# Compute future tuition

Tags: python

I have a problem I need to calculate future tuition depending on the input that the user puts. So for example the tuition is 5,000 per year and increases by 7% every year. If a user inputs 6 the program should print the total cost of tuition for years six, seven, eight and nine. So far I have this.

```
year = 1
n = int(input())
tuition = 5000
for i in range (n,n + 3):
    tuition = tuition * 1.07
    year = year + 1
print (tuition)
```

Comment: Okay, so what is the question? What's wrong with the code you've provided? Is there a problem?

Comment: It's not computing the tuition from the n year. It just says error.

Comment: Okay... So what's the error? Read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Got it, sorry. It just gives me a wrong answer. So if the input is 1 which means that it would calculate tuition starting from year one up to year 4 it just gives me 6125.215. When even for one year it is not a right amount.

Comment: But at year 1 the starting value is `5000`, and you do it for 3 years. In other words: `5000 * 1.07^3 = 6125.215`. Seems like your print is not properly indented given your explanation. And you also don't update the tuition to start at correct value then. You would need to do the calculation up to `n`, and then continue them from `n` to `n+3` while printing the result.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what the user inputs, your *for* loop will run through 3 iterations.

It looks like you're trying to add a 7% increase (compound) every year for 3 years.

You don't need a loop for that.

e.g.,

```
tuition = 5_000
years = 3
increase = 1.07 

print(tuition * increase ** years)
```

**Output:**

```
6125.215
```

Answer (score 0):

### A few hints

The problem with your program is that you are looping using a for loop but you are not using the value `i` within your for loop. You should use it. Additionally think about how many times your `print()` statement is executed. Only once, but you need it for every year so think about moving it into the for loop as well.

One other thing: `input()` takes a string as a parameter so you can provide some description of what a user is supposed to enter. You should use this as well to make your program usable.

```py
n = int(input("Please enter a start year:"))
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you should never call *int()* with the return value from *input()* without some form of error handling. A ValueError will arise if the entered string cannot be converted to int and the program will abort if it's not dealt with